# How to add Accept/Reject All Suggestions to a Google Doc Add-On

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm creating a GSuite Add-on with various menu items and want users to be able to accept/reject all suggestions in their current Doc.

The client-side javascript code to do this can be found here: https://blog.crozdesk.com/accept-all-changes-in-google-docs-with-one-click/

I've tried to incorporate this into my Add-On in the form of a prompt with two buttons. Here's the Apps Script code:

```
function suggestions() {
    var suggestions = [HTML as per below]
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(suggestions)
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(100);
    ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Accept/Reject All Suggestions');
}
```

Here's the html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <base target="_top">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
          </head>
        <body>
        <form>
        <div class="block" id="button-bar">
          <button class="blue" id="accept-all">Accept All Suggestions</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block" id="button-bar">
          <button class="blue" id="reject-all">Reject All Suggestions</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        <script>
        document.getElementById("accept-all").onclick = accept-all();
        document.getElementById("reject-all").onclick = reject-all();
        function accept-all() { 
         google.script.host.close();
         //below code from https://blog.crozdesk.com/accept-all-changes-in-google-docs-with-one-click/
         var d=document.getElementsByClassName("docos-accept-suggestion"); 
         d = Array.prototype.slice.call(d); 
         d.forEach(function(n){ 
          var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
          e.initEvent("click", true, false); 
          n.dispatchEvent(e,true); 
          e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
          e.initEvent("mousedown", true, false);
          n.dispatchEvent(e,true);
          e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
          e.initEvent("mouseup", true, false); 
          n.dispatchEvent(e,true); 
         }); 
        }
        function reject-all() { 
         google.script.host.close();
         //below code from https://blog.crozdesk.com/accept-all-changes-in-google-docs-with-one-click/         
         var d=document.getElementsByClassName("docos-reject-suggestion"); 
         d = Array.prototype.slice.call(d); 
         d.forEach(function(n){ 
          var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
          e.initEvent("click", true, false); 
          n.dispatchEvent(e,true); 
          e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
          e.initEvent("mousedown", true, false);
          n.dispatchEvent(e,true);
          e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
          e.initEvent("mouseup", true, false); 
          n.dispatchEvent(e,true); 
         }); 
        }
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The html is presented correctly within the prompt, but when I press either the "Accept All Suggestions" or "Reject All Suggestions" buttons a new tab is opened in the browser pointing to: https://[many-alphanumerics]-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel? with a blank page. The prompt doesn't close, despite "google.script.host.close();" being within both functions.

Is this possible or am I fighting a losing battle? Grateful for any pointers. If there's a simpler way to do this without the prompt (e.g. within the Apps Script function itself), also happy to hear suggestions on that.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the 'form' element? You don't really need it as there's no user input. Because your buttons are wrapped in a <form> tag, clicking on them also raises the 'submit' event of the form that redirects to the URL specified in the <form> 'action' attribute. Usually setting the 'action' attribute equal to "" will redirect to the page itself, but this doesn't seem to work in GAS.

Apparently, GAS-generated forms have default 'action' attribute that you can't override like this.

You could also wrap each button in its own <form> tag and then prevent redirect after submitting the form like this

```
window.onload = function(){

var form = document.getElementById('form1');
form1.addEventListener('submit', function(event){

  event.preventDefault();
  //call the function for this form


});

}
```

You won't need 'onclick' handlers for buttons in this case.

Comment: Thanks Anton. Removing the form element stopped the new tab being opened, but now when I click on the buttons nothing happens - the prompt doesn't even close which suggests that it's not even getting as far as "google.script.host.close();". FWIW - your second suggestion reverts to the original behaviour (i.e opens new tab, prompt doesn't close, nothing happens).